# What is purpose of checking data type size by CMake at configure step?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, build, configure

I am trying to build [BBS Studio](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio) project using [`cmake`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake).

For configuration and generating build files I am using this command.

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -S . -B build64 -DDepsPath=C:\Users\alokm\Downloads\dependencies2019\win64 -DQTDIR=C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64 -DVIRTUALCAM_GUID=e61ba6f1-ac3a-47b6-aaee-b537088061e4 -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES=Release
```

Those relevent log lines which I am examining are

```
C compiler: MSVC

-- Check size of __int64
-- Check size of __int64 - done
-- Check size of int64_t
-- Check size of int64_t - done
-- Check size of long long
-- Check size of long long - done
-- Check size of int32_t
-- Check size of int32_t - done
-- Check size of __int32
-- Check size of __int32 - done
-- Check size of long
-- Check size of long - done
-- Check size of int
-- Check size of int - done
-- Check size of unsigned long
-- Check size of unsigned long - done
-- Check size of unsigned int
-- Check size of unsigned int - done
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Check size of uint32_t
-- Check size of uint32_t - done
-- Check size of __uint32
-- Check size of __uint32 - failed
-- Check size of uint16_t
-- Check size of uint16_t - done
-- Check size of __uint16
-- Check size of __uint16 - failed
-- Check size of uint8_t
-- Check size of uint8_t - done
-- Check size of __uint8
-- Check size of __uint8 - failed
-- Check size of ssize_t
-- Check size of ssize_t - failed
-- Check size of SSIZE_T
-- Check size of SSIZE_T - failed
```

In this configure step what these log lines are about checking size of datatypes? What is meaning of these lines? What are purpose of checking size of datatypes?

Comment: See also the [documentation of `CHECK_TYPE_SIZE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckTypeSize.html)

Answer (score 3):

The reason is code portability. Standard [fixed-width integer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) types like `int32_t` are not required to be supported by all compilers and are supported since C99 (and C++11) only.

We can see [here](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/blob/81c2dac75e07c385dfd9cd1cffff193a53942edf/deps/jansson/CMakeLists.txt#L158) that the bundled `jansson` library needs specific-width integer types for JSON parsing. So for example, for a 32-bit integer it checks a few possibilities - `int32_t`, `__int32`, `long`, `int`:

```
# Check our 32 bit integer sizes
check_type_size (int32_t INT32_T)
check_type_size (__int32 __INT32)
check_type_size ("long" LONG_INT)
check_type_size ("int" INT)
if (HAVE_INT32_T)
   set (JSON_INT32 int32_t)
elseif (HAVE___INT32)
   set (JSON_INT32 __int32)
elseif (HAVE_LONG_INT AND (${LONG_INT} EQUAL 4))
   set (JSON_INT32 long)
elseif (HAVE_INT AND (${INT} EQUAL 4))
   set (JSON_INT32 int)
else ()
   message (FATAL_ERROR "Could not detect a valid 32-bit integer type")
endif ()
```

Arguably, the configuration process would go faster if it performed one check at a time until a desired type is found (in most cases the first choice would be sufficient).